# Unix Shell String appending to delete file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

I am writing a script to delete a log file from a specific location. I would pass a directory and filename as a parameter to function. This function will delete this file.

Code is below

```
#!/bin/sh
folder= '/apps/applications/jboss-as/servers/domain/log/'
logfile=temp.log

delFile(){
echo 'you will delete $1 $2'
file_to_del='$1$2'
rm -rf $file_to_del
}

delFile $folder $logfile
```

Output is as below.

you will delete $1 $2

Could you tell how should I update this code for my requirement?

Comment: Remove the space between the equal sign and the path in your second line.

Comment: Thanks @Bernhard It is right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by Alberto you need to use `"`. Also you have to remove the space before the folder path.

So try this one:

```
#!/bin/sh
folder=/apps/applications/jboss-as/servers/domain/log/
logfile=temp.log

delFile(){
echo "you will delete $1$2"
file_to_del="$1$2"
rm -rf "$file_to_del"
}

delFile "$folder" "$logfile"
```

Answer (score 2):

In bash you don't get variable substitution if you use single quotes `'`.

You should change `file_to_del='$1$2'` to `file_to_del="$1$2"`.

On the subject: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/varsubn.html

Comment: Your answer worked! Accepted tod's answer to help him reach 1k :)